# Combine two stored procedures to perform separate SQL Server database searches

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, search, stored-procedures

I am searching a SQL Server database using a stored procedure. I have it working perfectly displaying in a repeater for the text box which searches for the name of house. In the code you can see it looks for one stored procedure to do the search. Can anyone help on how to combine the two stored procedures into one? They both work individually but I need to get the one stored procedure to be capable of doing both searches. The dropdown list labelled `townland` is separate.

[image]

Code:

```
public void DisplaySearchResults(string strSearch)
{
    // Display search results in repeater
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spiSearchByString", new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAYDDD;Initial Catalog=HOB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ID; Password=password"));
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchString", strSearch);

    cmd.Connection.Open();

    rptDataSearch.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    rptDataSearch.DataBind();
}
```

Stored procedure for searching the name:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spiSearchByString
    @SearchString varchar(50)
AS 
    SELECT 
        Houses.Name, Houses.Id, Houses.Townland, 
        Houses.Near, Houses.Status, Houses.Built, Houses.Image  
    FROM 
        Houses
    WHERE 
        (Houses.Name LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%' OR 
         Houses.Id LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%')
    ORDER BY 
        Houses.Name 

    RETURN
```

Stored procedure for searching the near:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.NearSearch
    @SearchString varchar(50)
AS 
    SELECT 
        Houses.Name, Houses.Id, Houses.Townland, Houses.Near, 
        Houses.Status, Houses.Built, Houses.Image  
    FROM 
        Houses
    WHERE 
        (Houses.Near LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%' 
         OR Houses.Id LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%')
    ORDER BY 
        Houses.Name 

    RETURN
```

Comment: What SQL server and version are you using?  What .NET framework version and ASP.NET version?

Comment: Usig SQL server 2008 and .Net 4.5 @cxw

Comment: Do you mean that both searches should always be executed? Or do you mean you want a single proc that can handle both searches. i.e. The user will only ever perform either a 'Near' or 'Name' search but the proc handles both.

Comment: Or do you want one stored procedure to return houses that match both the Name and Near criteria (if any)?

Comment: Yes you have it. I am looking how to write one stored procedure to return houses that match both the Name and Near criteria (if any). Both of the stored procedure I have already work perfectly individually so if there is a way to combine them. @cxw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have one proc that does both with the following procedure. It takes in both parameters and based upon which one is NULL. Returns the relevant data. It also allows for both to be specified as well and for the data to be filtered by both `Name` and `Near`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CombinedSearch
(
    @HouseNearSearch VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @HouseNameSearch VARCHAR(50) = NULL
)
AS
    SELECT
        Houses.Name
        ,Houses.Id
        ,Houses.Townland
        ,Houses.Near
        ,Houses.Status
        ,Houses.Built
        ,Houses.IMAGE
    FROM Houses
    WHERE (@HouseNear IS NULL OR (Houses.Near LIKE '%' + @HouseNearSearch + '%' OR Houses.Id LIKE '%' + @HouseNearSearch + '%'))
 OR   (@HouseName IS NULL OR  (Houses.Name LIKE '%' + @HouseNameSearch + '%' OR Houses.Id LIKE '%' + @HouseNameSearch + '%'))
    ORDER BY Houses.Name
    RETURN
```

Your code will need updating to identify which parameter to assign the search string to.

Comment: This is working but only displays one result when there could be up to ten. @Xtrnts

Comment: Just change `WHERE (something) AND (something)` for `OR`

Comment: But in your comment you say you want match `BOTH`. I think should be OR, otherwise you should provide some data sample in [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1b72/2)

Comment: Just edited my post. Should've been an OR instead of an AND as @JuanCarlosOropeza says.

Comment: @Xtrnts  - Gentlemen, Thank you. Working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have worked on solutions which return multiple record sets using a single data reader.  You may have to make and call a containing stored procedure which accepts all of the parameters and calls both procedures in turn.  You can then follow this code example to read each result set in a single call; [How To Handle Multiple Results by Using the DataReader in Visual C# .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311274)